# Return values from a child dag triggered without execution date using TriggerDagRunOperator

Tags: python, airflow

**Context:**
I have a set of operators in a dag that perform operations based on the dag_run configuration(let's call it child dag: dag_c). The child dag can be triggered by other dags (let's call it Parent dag_a & dag_b). Parent dag_a & dag_b runs at the same time.

**Use case:**
My use case is to get a return value from dag c to dag a and dag b. The return value is unique to the parent dag which triggered the child dag. Since dag A & B can run at the same time, I cannot use execution_date. The code in dag c is common for both dag a & b, and I don't want to copy-paste the same code in both dags.

**Problem Statement:**
Without setting the execution date, I am not able to get the return value using the xcom_pull method

So far I have tried :

To push the return value using the xcom_push method in child dag, but the child dags execution is in future and value is not available in parent dag
Tried to do an xcom_push using the parent dag's execution, but it failed since we can not set an x_com in the past. The job fails with error: 'execution_date can not be in the past'
Use Subdags for dag c generation and call it in dag A & B. This method solved my use case, but sub dags are not recommended in [airflow](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/subdags), I would like to know if there are any better methods to solve this problem.
I am using airflow 2.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

This was answered as on the [Apache Airflow GitHub Discussion](https://github.com/apache/airflow/discussions/17205) board but to bring these threads together for everyone:

> Maybe try Airflow Variables instead of `XCom` in this case. You could use the `Variable.set()` method to write the return value required. There would not be any `execution_date` constraints on the value that's set and the value is still centrally accessible by dag_a and dag_b.